# Ruby hash based on indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, syntax, indentation

Can I someway introduce indentation based hashes in ruby? Something like coffescript hashes.

```
a: 1
  b: 
    c: 3
    d: 4
  e:
    f: 'qwe'
```

Comment: All solutions have been seen by me use 'preprocessing' technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can either implement a method to parse hashes from strings using indentation as delimiters, or, as @AJcodez suggested:

```
require 'psych'
require 'yaml'

yash = <<EOT  # type hashes like this
---
:a:
- 1
- :b:
    :c: 3
    :d: 4
  :e:
    :f: qwe
EOT

hash = YAML.load yash
=> {:a=>[1, {:b=>{:c=>3, :d=>4}, :e=>{:f=>"qwe"}}]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not directly, but I think you'd like [YAML](http://rhnh.net/2011/01/31/yaml-tutorial).

Comment: Sure, I thought about this solution, but my goal is to combine the slimmest hash definition and ruby code in single file. Thanks!

Comment: @FUT: then you can write a coffeescript analog for ruby, with indentation-based syntax and whatnot. Name it Emerald or something like that :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev nice joke! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you squint your eyes and make a wish then the regular syntax is kind of similar to what your are looking for.

```
h = { a: 1,
        b:{ 
          c: 3,
          d: 4},
        e:{
          f: 'qwe'}}
```